# Retrieving dynamic pop up menu items

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu, onclicklistener

I have implemented a pop up menu on button click as follows

```
val menu = PopupMenu(activity, view)
    brands.forEach {
        menu.getMenu().add(it)
    }
    menu.show()
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this)
    menu.show()
```

My question is how can i retrieve the selected item name in onclickListener since i cant reference to the data which will be added dynamically.

OnclickListener

```
override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    //How do i obtain selected item name?
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call item.title to get the label of clicked item.

```
override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val title = item.title
    return true
}
```